# If $P(A) ,\ P(B|A)$ and $P(B|A’)$ are given, how do we find the value of $P(B)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> If $P(A)=\frac{2}{5} , P(B|A)=\frac{1}{3} , P(B|A’)=\frac{1}{4}$ how do we find the value of $P(B)$?

I tried using the conditional probability formula but the question seems to be lacking information. I do believe that they are not independent events however

Comment: Use Venn Diagrams for clarity in these questions

Answer (score 1):

Either event $A$ happens or not, that is, $A'$ happens.

By definition, $P(B|A)=P(B\cap A)/P(A)$; similarly, $P(B|A')=P(B\cap A')/P(A')$.

So \begin{align*}P(B)&=P(B\cap A) + P(B\cap A')\\
&=P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|A')P(A')\\&=\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{3}{5}=\frac{17}{60}\end{align*}

Comment: I don’t understand where you got that equation from

Comment: It's the *law of total probability*.

Comment: @user812633 Probability is additive on disjoint sets. Since $B$ is the disjoint union of $B \cap A$ and $B \cap A'$, we have $P(B) = P(B \cap A) + P(B \cap A')$.

Comment: How do you know it is disjoint? @Bungo

Comment: If $\omega$ is in $B \cap A$ then it's in $A$. If $\omega$ is also in $B \cap A'$ then it's in $A'$. But $A$ and $A'$ have no elements in common, so there is no such $\omega$.